# Android Custom AutoComplete textview image and text

Tags: android, autocomplete

I have a user list. Every user has name and image. I want to display these users in AutoCompleteTextView. Users' name and image must be displayed in autoCompleteTextView.So I am customizing AutoCompleteTextView to display images and text. I get help from wptrafficanalyzer site.
See: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-autocompletetextview-to-display-images-and-text-in-the-suggestion-list-using-simpleadapter-in-android/

But images are used in drawable folder in project. But I want to use from url to image. Should I use a custom adapter instead of simple adapter?  How to do this case?

Thanks

Comment: I'd use custom adapter. Take a look https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper